# Navigation bar doesn't display right when I change the bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

In default bootstrap in ASP.NET MVC, the page is just fine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkkvA.jpg)
[image]

But whenever I change the bootstrap, what ever the bootstrap is, the navigation bar goes like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHbL6.jpg)

[image]
how do I fix this? I only changed the BudleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
    "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/Content/journal-bootstrap.css",
    "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Comment: what do you mean bu change bootstrap ?

Comment: in the last set of codes: "~/Content/journal-bootstrap.css", the default is "~/Content/bootstrap.css",

Comment: if you add "bootstrap.css" instead of "journal-bootstrap.css". what happens ?

Comment: the default is "~/Content/bootstrap.css", so if I download the journal-bootstrap.css and put it inside my project, I need to change the "~/Content/bootstrap.css" into "~/Content/journal-bootstrap.css", but if I do that, the second image happens

Comment: ok, can you please share the link from where you got jounral-bootstrap.css

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have override my bootstrap css with journal bootsrap css as you mentioned and it is look like this.

[link for bootstrap css](https://www.easysensing.pt/static/bootstrap/themes/journal/css/bootstrap.css)

[image: Image after added journal Boostrap css]

Comment: how come it doesnt work that way to me? i even tried vs 2019 and 2017 and the nav bar goes the same.

Comment: is there anyway i could download that project? ill see if it is my machine that causes that

Comment: wow, did you modify the css? i copied and pasted the css you provided on mine and it worked fine. what did you modify?

Comment: may be your css was conflict with other. it is good that your issue is resolved

Comment: its funny because i was following Mosh's tutorial on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Voso411Vs at 23:41. he didnt do much and i just followed it.

Comment: btw, can you please point out which specifically caused that error in display?

Comment: i do not know exactly what was the issue, but i can say whatever css you used may be outdated. that can be reason of it.

Answer (score 0):

Each bootstrap has its own properties. 
The one you are using includes some properties which makes the navigation bar display that way.

The priority is given to those which are called the latest, hence even if you have the same bootstrap, it displays according to the latest bootstrap what you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Read the features of bootstrap and apply right CSS class in page and you can see the design. Ensure that CSS style loaded in bundles and you mapped correct path in bundle_config file.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/